# Stop the loop in sounddevice audio output

Tags: python, loops, audio, python-sounddevice

The problem is when I am using sounddevice's loop option to loop a playback, I cannot get it to stop.

```
import soundfile as sf
import sounddevice as sd

weight = 1.4

data, fs = sf.read('sound.wav')
sd.play(data * weight, fs, blocking=True,loop=True)
sd.stop()
```

How to stop the loop, after it has started. Is it possible to write a function such that when the function is called the loop stops and the audio stream is closed?

Comment: Does sd.stop() not work? Does it error or just not stop sound output?

Comment: It does not show any error, sounddevice.stop() / sd.stop() doesn't work when sd.play(....loop=True) i.e when loop is on.

Comment: But that is what I am looking for, how to stop a loop with a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `blocking=True` which does not allow for any other functions to be run before this exits. Combined with `loop=True`, this produces an infinite loop.

What you want is:

```
import soundfile as sf
import sounddevice as sd

weight = 1.4

data, fs = sf.read('sound.wav')
sd.play(data * weight, fs,loop=True)
sd.stop()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.